Convert Newtonsoft JObject to System.Text.Json JsonObject
I am trying to upgrade my solution from using Newtonsoft to System.Text.Json. One of the nuget packages that I can consume calls REST APIs which return complex objects that it deserializes using Newtonsoft. I am not in a position to modify this nuget package, and I would rather not write my own client to consume the REST APIs.
One of the API endpoints returns complex objects, example:
// ComplexResource is defined in the nuget package and is annotated with Newtonsoft
public class ComplexResource
{
   [JsonProperty("uuid")]
   public Guid Uuid;

   [JsonProperty("child_resources")]
   public Dictionary<string, object> ChildResources;
}


The ChildResources Dictionary<string, object> is structured as follows:

The key is the name of the type (e.g., PlanResource)
The value is itself another complex type, one of

In the case of multiple items, a JArray of some more JObject items
In the case of a single item, a JObject



This is where the fun begins. I want to deserialize all of the ChildResources items into my solution's representation of each item (e.g.,PlanResource). The PlanResource object in my solution is annotated correctly with System.Text.Json attributes (e.g., JsonPropertyName).
Unfortuantely, I can't find a way to do this without reserializing the dictionary's values back out to JSON, example:
// Step 0: Get value from dictionary
var complexResource = ... uses nuget package, returns ComplexResource ...
var resourceData = complexResource.ChildResources["PlanResource"];
 
// Step 1: Serialize back out **with Newtonsoft**
var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resourceData);

// Step 2: Deserialize **with System.Text.Json**
var actualResource = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(jsonString);

// Step 3: Operate on PlanResource as normal
actualResource.LastUpdated = ...

This seems inefficient and requires a lot of serializing and deserializing.
Is there a more direct way to convert these objects, without writing some kind of custom mapper for each individual resource type?

Since System.Text.Json is designed to deserialize from UTF8 byte streams, you might get better performance serializing to and deserializing from a MemoryStream.

You asked, Is there a more direct way to convert these objects, without writing some kind of custom mapper for each individual resource type? -- basically no.  You would need to write some converter.  How can I serialize a Newtonsoft JToken to JSON using System.Text.Json? shows an example of a converter that serializes a JToken with System.Text.Json, you would to write the opposite.  Are you actually asking for that, or is your question literally do I need to write one?

Incidentally, in your code you do JsonSerializer.Deserialize(jsonString).  JsonSerializer.Deserialize() does not have a non-generic overload that takes a single string argument.  You need to specify the target type.  If How can I serialize a Newtonsoft JToken to JSON using System.Text.Json? doesn't answer your question, could you please share a [mcve] showing what actualResource is and how you are using it?  Thanks!
